# spring security concurrent session not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 I have implemented the Spring security and its working fine but, I do not want to allow concurrent logins using same credentials. 
1. I have added the Listener "HttpSessionEventPublisher" to web.xml and used the "Session management" tag in spring security to implement the concurrency control but it is not working Following is the complete Code:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginError" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/sessionTimeout" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/requestNewPassword" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="permitAll()" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/sessionExpired" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/error" access="isAnonymous()" />


    <form-login  login-page="/login"
                 username-parameter="userId"
                 password-parameter="password"
                 authentication-success-handler-ref="cdatSuccessHandler"
                 authentication-failure-url="/loginError" />

    <!-- <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" invalid-session-url="/sessionTimeout">
    </session-management> -->

    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/sessionTimeout" />
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <csrf/>

    <!-- <access-denied-handler error-page="/sessionExpired"/>  -->

    <headers>
        <xss-protection enabled="true" block="true"/>
    </headers>

</http>

<authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
    <authentication-provider ref="cdatAuthenticationProvider"> </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Authentication provider class

```
package com.component.cdat.security.configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import     org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.component.cdat.project.bean.MappProjectUser;
import com.component.cdat.user.bean.User;
import com.component.cdat.user.services.UserService;

@Component("cdatAuthenticationProvider")
public class CDATAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String loginId = authentication.getName().trim();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    if(loginId == null || password == null || loginId.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
        // throw exception
        System.out.println("username or password is empty!!");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    User user = userService.getUserByUserName(loginId);

    if(user == null || !loginId.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getUserName())){
        System.out.println("User Not Found!!");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if(!password.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getPassword())){
        System.out.println("Pasword is incorrect!!");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(user);

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user){

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    List<MappProjectUser> userAuthorityList = userService.getUserRole(user.getUserId());

    for(MappProjectUser userAuthority : userAuthorityList){
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userAuthority.getUserType().getShortDesc()));
    }
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: password.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getPassword()) might not be a good idea from a security point of view. How have you tested and came to the conclusion it was not working ? (for example, several tabs inside the same browser usually use the same session for a given site).

Comment: No...I have used different browsers and also tried to open the link in incognito mode but it allowed me to log in with same credentials. And what should we use to compare password for better security?

Comment: For the password, do not ignore the case.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-mgmt) (this is for spring security 3.1) :

```
  <http>
      ...
      <session-management>
          <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
      </session-management>
  </http>
```

> This will prevent a user from logging in multiple times - **a second login will cause the first to be invalidated**. Often you would prefer to prevent a second login, in which case you can use

```
<http>
    ...
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

---

Try to add `error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"` to the `concurrency-control` tag, to see if it's working. Be aware of the drawback of this concurrency control : if the user closes his browser without logging out, he will have no way to log in before the session timeout (which often is 30 minutes... so he won't be able to get access to the website for the next 30 minutes).

Comment: I have gone through the spring security reference documentation, and have implemented this concurrency control with the help of this document only and I have tried the above `error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"` but it didn't work.